matlab:Plot the relative error for de Casteljau algorithm when evaluating polynomials
I want to compare the error performance of de Casteljau algorithm and Horner algorithm when evaluating the same polynomial.
I have chosen the ill-conditioning polynomial given by Wilkinson:

p(t)=\prod_{k=1}^{20}(t-\frac{k}{20})

In matlab,I use these two algorithms to evaluate p(t) on [0,1],obtaining the computed solution in floating-arithmetic.I also use the symbolic math tool to get the exact solution.
Finally I'd like to compare the relative error of two algorithms and plot it.
below are my codes in matlab:
syms k x;
tmp = symprod(x-k/20, k, [1 20]);
P(x)=expand(tmp);%the polynomial

down_coeff=coeffs(P(x),'All');%Coefficients in descending order
up_coeff=flip(down_coeff);%Coefficients in ascending order

Bezier_coeff=sym(monomial_to_bernstein(up_coeff));%Coefficients in Bernstein basis

t=1/72:1/36:71/72;

sol_Horner=zeros(1,length(t));
sol_DC=zeros(1,length(t));

sol_exact=P(t);
for k=1:length(t)
    sol_DC(k)=DC(Bezier_coeff,t(k));
    sol_Horner(k)=Horner(down_coeff,t(k));
end

%obtain the relative error
DC_rel_error=(abs(sol_exact-sol_DC)./abs(sol_exact));
Hor_rel_error=(abs(sol_exact-sol_Horner)./abs(sol_exact));

plot(t,log10(DC_rel_error),'r');
hold on
plot(t,log10(Hor_rel_error),'b');
legend('de Casteljau','Horner');
xlabel('x');
ylabel('log10(relative error)');

I think the codes of two algorithms have no wrong:
function B = DC(P,t)
% de Casteljau algorithm for bezier curves
n = length(P) - 1; 
Q = double(P);
r=1-t;
for k = 1:n
    for i = 1:(n - k + 1)
        Q(i) = r * Q(i) + t * Q(i + 1);
    end
end
B=Q(1);

function y = Horner(P, t)   
    n = length(P);
    P=double(P);
    y = P(1);
    for i = 1:n-1
        y = y * t + P(i+1);
    end
end

and the function monomial_to_bernstein works well
function gamma_B = monomial_to_bernstein(gamma_M)
    n=length(gamma_M)-1;
    gamma_B = zeros(1, n+1);
    gamma_B(1) = gamma_M(1);
    tilde_gamma_M=zeros(1,n+1);
    for i = 2:n+1
        tilde_gamma_M(1:i-1)=gamma_B(1:i-1);
        tilde_gamma_M(i)=-gamma_M(i) / nchoosek(n, i-1);
        gamma_B(i)=-diff(tilde_gamma_M(1:i),i-1);
    end
end

however,I can't get the expected result as the paper gives.
the actual result
the expected result

You get the exact solution from the evaluation of the product before expansion. In P(t) you are using some Horner or other evaluation on the already unrecoverably rounded coefficients. It would also be better to get the Bernstein coefficients directly from the product expression.
